# UITableView issue in iPad?

Tags: ios, ipad, uitableview, xcode4.3

I am working in a iPad application. I'm using a `UITableView` to create a table and insert 2 `UIImageView`s in each cell. I tried to set image in both `UIImageView`s, but index path values start from 0,1,2,3,4 etc...

Each `UIImageView` has same image in first cell. How to fix this issue?

[image]

Example:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // ImageArray have 5images;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{


    return [ImageArray count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    imgView1.image = [imageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; 
    imgView2.image = [imageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; 
 }
```

Comment: where u set UIImageView , i mean it set to cell.contentView ???

Comment: and wt u want to display in out put?

Comment: [Imagearray count] = 5, then i have add to each uiimageview img1.image = [imagearray objectatindex:indexpath.row];
img2.image = [imagearray objectatindex:indexpath.row];

Comment: iPatel - yes i have set cell.contentview add subview:img1

Answer (score 0):

After formatting your code it becomes clear that you are assigning the same image from the array to each of the two image views. You will need an imageViewArray that has the double amount of members.

Also, you should not check for the count of your image array but for the `row` of your index path.